# Windows Form Application - Transparent PictureBox Image overwrites Form Transparency

Tags: c#, windows, forms, transparency

So I set the background of my form transparent by:

```
this.BackColor = Color.Red;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
```

Which works fine, but when I now want to display a semitransparent image with a textbox on top of that, the transparent background of my form becomes red where I draw the transparent image.

Any ideas on how I can stop that from happening ?

Cheers!

Comment: "semi-transparent" is the usual problem, the image probably has pixels with the alpha channel set to a value other than 255.  Photoshop likes creating them.  That changes the BackColor color of the pixel, making is less Red and thus no longer matches the TransparencyKey.  So becomes visible.  You need a per-pixel alpha layered window, it is incompatible with TextBox.  WPF can do it.

Comment: is there a code example for the per-pixel alpha layered window around?

Comment: Just google the term, second hit is a C# project.  Don't use it.